# How do I unit/widget test AnimationController

Tags: flutter, dart

```
type here
```

I have a widget to test and it includes an animation controller that I need to test.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:lottie/lottie.dart';
import 'package:squadx/core/resource_path.dart';
import 'package:squadx/pages/splash_page/controller/splash_controller.dart';

class SplashPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SplashPage> createState() => _SplashPageState();
}

class _SplashPageState extends State<SplashPage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    animationController = AnimationController(vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetBuilder<SplashController>(
        init: SplashController(),
        builder: (controller) {
          return Scaffold(
            body: Lottie.asset(ResourcePath.splash_logo_json,
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                controller: animationController,
                width: 1.sw,
                height: 1.sh, onLoaded: (composition) {
              animationController
                ..duration = composition.duration
                ..forward().whenComplete(() {
                  controller.checkVersion();
# patrolTest('On Load test', (PatrolTester $) async {
    // Arrange

    final animationController = $.tester.widget<AnimationController>(
      $(SplashPage).$(AnimationController),
    );
    var callbackCalled = false;

    const widget = SplashPage();
    await $.pumpWidgetAndSettle(
      ScreenUtilInit(
        builder: (context, child) => const GetMaterialApp(
          home: widget,
        ),
      ),
    );


    animationController.addStatusListener((status) {
      if (status == AnimationStatus.completed && !callbackCalled) {
        callbackCalled = true;

`your text`
        expect(splashController.checkVersion, isTrue);
      }
    });

    // Trigger the animation
    animationController.forward();
    // Wait for the animation to complete
    await $.tester.pumpAndSettle();
  });
```

'AnimationController' doesn't conform to the bound 'Widget' of the type parameter 'T'.
Try using a type that is or is a subclass of 'Widget' --< That's the blocker I get. I need help por favor as I have a job to do and tasks to go through